# Do type annotations improve or hinder performance for abstract types?

Tags: types, julia

The Julia documentation seems to be conflicting about when to use type annotations.

From the [Types documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Declarations):

> The `::` operator can be used to attach type annotations to expressions and variables in programs. There are two primary reasons to do this:
>
> 1. [...]
> 2. To provide extra type information to the compiler, which can then
>    improve performance in some cases.

From [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Annotate-values-taken-from-untyped-locations):

> Type annotation will not enhance (and can actually hinder) performance
> if the type is abstract, or constructed at run-time.

For the purposes of illustration, suppose I had the following hierarchy:

```
abstract type Character end
struct SpaceMarine <: Character end
# I've used the abstract type Character as a type annotation.
svetlana :: Character = SpaceMarine()
```

Is using type annotations the way I did (note that it's abstract), hindering performance or helping it?

In this case, `svetlana` can only be a subtype of `Character`, which is the behaviour that I require.

Just as in C# or Java, you can do `Character svetlana = new SpaceMarine()`, `svetlana` can only be any subtype of `Character`.

If using type annotations is hurting performance, how can I keep `svetlana` a type of `Character`?

I don't want someone to write `svetlana = "Space Marine"`. In this case, it's now a `String`.

Comment: [This question was discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412316).

Comment: "...hindering performance or helping it?" It could also be neutral, i.e. has no effect on performance.

Answer (score 4):

In my view, and given the illustration, it is neutral.

I find it often easier to benchmark this type of question because I can then make it more pertinent to the problem at hand.
Below is a short example based on the illustration given in the question. Only I added a field because otherwise, Julia will optimize away operations on the Struct.

```
using BenchmarkTools

abstract type C end
struct S <: C 
    f 
end

function ttest(n)
    t1::C =S(0)
    i = 0
    for i in 1:n
        t1 = S(i)
    end
    return t1
end
function stest(n)
    t1::S =S(0)
    i = 0
    for i in 1:n
        t1= S(i)
    end
    return t1
end

@benchmark ttest(1000000)
@benchmark stest(1000000)
```

and this gives the following for the Abstract Type version:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 532 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  8.891 ms …  10.661 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 10.87%
 Time  (median):     9.057 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   9.393 ms ± 499.180 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.06% ±  5.19%

       █▅                                                      
  ▃▃▄▆███▇▆▄▃▃▂▂▁▂▁▂▁▁▂▁▂▁▂▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▃▅▅▄▇▅▆▅▄▃▂▂▂ ▃
  8.89 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        10.2 ms <

 Memory estimate: 15.25 MiB, allocs estimate: 999489.
```

And this for Struct version:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 533 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  8.841 ms …  10.213 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 11.04%
 Time  (median):     9.048 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   9.381 ms ± 494.894 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.04% ±  5.18%

         ▇█                                                    
  ▂▁▃▃▄▅▆██▇▇▄▃▂▂▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂▂▂▅▅▅▇▆▅▅▃▃▃ ▃
  8.84 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        10.2 ms <

 Memory estimate: 15.25 MiB, allocs estimate: 999489.
```

From there, it seems to me that both versions behave similarly about performance.

I used Julia 1.6.3; this behavior might be different in another version. However, it is straightforward to test it.

Comment: The benchmark does not call any functions with subtype-specific implementations. I would imagine that once you have multiple possible methods under the same abstract type, the JIT compiler would end up resorting to dynamic dispatch underneath, instead of calling the specific method known ahead of time, thus slightly degrading performance.

Comment: That makes sense, although I handle that educated opinion as a hypothesis that can be tested through adequate benchmarking. Given the high-level nature of the question, it is difficult, to address all the potential sub-topic. I feel that a follow-up, more specific question would be better addressed in a separate question.